# How can I change the labelling of an equation?

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

How can I change the labelling of an equation? Instead of `(1.1)`, `(1.2)` I want to have `(Equation 1.1)`, `(Equation 1.2)`, ...

Document class is `scrbook`.

I use the following related packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
```

Example of an equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:example}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
```

Comment: What should happen with the references to equations? For example, should `\ref{eqn:example}` also return `Equation X.Y`? Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're loading the `amsmath` package, you could make use of that package's `\tagform@` macro to achieve your objective.

Note that you will not be able to use `\eqref` to create cross-references to equations; I suggest you load the `cleveref` package and use `\cref` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces(Equation #1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\begin{equation} 
\label{eqn:example}
a+b=c
\end{equation}

A cross-reference to \cref{eqn:example}.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you're willing to load the `mathtools` package (which automatically loads `amsmath`), you could make use of the `\newtagform` macro. (I'm not posting a second screenshot, as the output of the following example looks just like the one above.)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\newtagform{Eq}{(Equation }{)}
\usetagform{Eq}

\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\begin{equation} 
\label{eqn:example}
a+b=c
\end{equation}

A cross-reference to \cref{eqn:example}.
\end{document}
```